# writing fortran config file

Tags: fortran, configuration-files

I would like to know if there is a way to write namelist in a programmatic  way ?

I would like to write differente part of namelist giving name parameter and value

does someone already do that ?

Regards

Comment: It is unclear to me what you are asking.  Could you give an example of what you want?

Comment: what the @@}¹~#{ previous answers and my full description has desappear, once again:  i have a big program that i have to test with multiples configurations. As it is impossible to write all possibles in file. I 'm writing a test tool in python, so i have an array of listname and parameters with values i have to test and i want to switch to. As i haven't library or easy way to write listname i asking if i could create listname routine in fortran compilate it and using it trough python langage.
To do that i need to pass listname, parameter and value as arguments ...

Comment: I think it might be easiest if you write a different file for each configuration and name it something like `run001.nml`, `run002.nml`, and so on. Then all you have to do is change the filename of the `nml` file read in.

Comment: It is already what i do, but i have to write lots of run (>1000) so i can't do it manualy ...

Comment: How about getting the current time (in Silverfrost it is time@ but on your system it may be different), take the colons out, concatenate .nml and use that as the filename.  That is, unless you do more than one per second.  You might also need to add the date (date@ in Silverfrost) if you are doing this over several days.